# I am getting CORS policy issue on one of my Magento 1 project

Tags: cors, policy

I am getting CORS policy issue on one of my Magento 1 project. the error as follow

Access to XMLHttpRequest at abc.com from origin xyz.com has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I already used "Header set X-Frame-Options "xyz.com"" in htaccess file under abc.com server.

I am calling an iframe of abc.com from xyz.com and at that time I am getting above error and popup is not opening due to above error.

Can any one let me know how can I solve this issue.

I already used "Header set X-Frame-Options "xyz.com"" in htaccess file under abc.com server.

I am calling an iframe of abc.com from xyz.com and at that time I am getting above error and popup is not opening due to above error.

Can any one let me know how can I solve this issue.